# WP API and Proxy

Tags: wp-api, proxy

I'm looking to implement a WordPress API service using the WP REST API plugin. However, I do not want the frontend to access the API directly so I'm opting to implementing an API Proxy.

- Can the WP REST API work behind a proxy?
- Has anyone ever used the WP REST API behind a proxy?
- Can anyone recommend an api proxy service that worked well with it?

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want the frontend to interact directly with the API? What benefit do you gain from adding another layer?

Comment: added security? I'm not comfortable with using wordpress as a backend service nor is the WP REST API plugin mature enough to be reliable

Answer (score 2):

Using a proxy is important when you cannot store your authentication credentials securely. One encounters this problem when building single page applications with client-side JavaScript Frameworks like *Angular* or *Ember*. [This blog entry](http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/) by Alex Bilbie nicely summarises the issue.

As a side project, involving a Angular/Ionic/Cordova application and WordPress, I'm building a proxy plugin for the *WP REST API* in order to communicate securely with the API. The code [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/mensch/WP-REST-API-Proxy), should you wish to check it out. It's a personal project (currently running inside a Vagrant box) geared towards understanding the API and polishing my Angular/Ionic skillset and based on my limited understanding of the OAuth spec, so there's bound to be a lot of bugs and other issues.

But to answer your three questions:

- The REST API works behind a proxy;
- I'm using both plugins (REST API and API proxy) as a primary datasource;
- I'm not aware of any proxy services that work with the WP REST API, but a quick Google search lists some generic tutorials by [Apigee](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/build-simple-api-proxy) and [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html).

**EDIT**: I started working on my proxy attempt when version 1 of WP API was still in development and there are now several other authentication options, apart from Basic Auth and OAuth1. [JWT](http://jwt.io) based authentication seems to be a more streamlined option as opposed to a proxy. I'm currently experimenting with [this JWT plugin](https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth) developed for the API. Still uncertain about the security implications, though, as is [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891741/how-to-secure-rest-api-for-spa-and-mobile-app-using-cordova). [This provides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21175036/196750) an interesting, but rather bleak general overview.

Comment: Some good insight here man....hope you experiment does well. I'll look into your stuff though.